# From Two Dimensional Array To One Dimensional Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, fuelphp

Hey,
I'm using FuelPHP and doing like this...

```
$query =
  \DB::select( 'username' )
    ->from( 'users' )
    ->execute()
    ->as_array();
```

I'm getting array as shown below.

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [username] => daGrevis
  )

  [1] => Array
  (
    [username] => whatever
  )

  [2] => Array
  (
    [username] => foobar
  )

)
```

It's definitely not what I need. Here's example of "ideal array" for me:

```
Array
(
  [0] => daGrevis
  [1] => whatever
  [2] => foobar
)
```

So how can I get "ideal array"? Maybe I do something wrong in the query... if no... how can I convert array #1 to array #2? Using loops maybe? Or there is built-in function? I'm confused.

Comment: That's the problem with bad frameworks reinventing the wheel. In PDO you would write `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)`.

Comment: @nikic Are you speaking about Fuel or all PHP frameworks in general? If only about Fuel... then it's okey for it, because it's only in beta. )

Comment: I'm talking about any framework, which, instead of simply using the very well designed interfaces that PDO provides, uses some reimplementation using mysqli/mysql.

Comment: This is nothing to do with frameworks, this is how native MySQL bindings return the data by default. We can add a method in to return arrays like that easily enough but there are plenty of insanely simple solutions to this basic array structure issue that have been around for decades.

Comment: See as well: [Turning multidimensional array into one-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611313/turning-multidimensional-array-into-one-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with Fuel natively:

```
$query = \DB::select( 'username' )
           ->from( 'users' )
           ->execute()
           ->as_array(null, 'username');
```

This will return exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, a foreach loop should do the trick:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($query as $result_num => $sub_array)
{
    $new_array[$result_num] = $sub_array[username];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do a foreach loop to convert it, something like this:

```
$arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr1 as &$value) {
array_push($arr2, $value[username]);
}
```