# Turning multidimensional array into one-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been banging my head on this one for a while now.

I have this multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => foo
            [1] => bar
            [2] => hello
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => world
            [1] => love
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stack
            [1] => overflow
            [2] => yep
            [3] => man
        )
```

And I need to get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => hello
    [3] => world
    [4] => love
    [5] => stack
    [6] => overflow
    [7] => yep
    [8] => man
)
```

Any ideas?

All other solutions I found solve multidimensional arrays with different keys. My arrays use simple numeric keys only.

Comment: Can the arrays be nested more than one level?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+flatten+mutlidimensional+array).

Comment: [look @ my solution in this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6940217/multidimensional-array-to-array/13143579#13143579

Answer (score 90):

```
array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', array())
```

Example:

```
$a = array(array(1, 2, 3), array(4, 5, 6));
$result = array_reduce($a, 'array_merge', array());
```

Result:

```
array[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Comment: This is not necessarily the best way to do it, it may be somewhat cryptic for one; I just like the functional approach and writing one-liners for the exercise. ;o)

Comment: Second argument could be just 'array_merge'.

Answer (score 42):

The PHP [`array_merge`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_merge) function can flatten your array:

```
$flat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

In case the original array has a higher depth than 2 levels, the SPL in PHP has a [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/RecursiveArrayIterator) you can use to flatten it:

```
$flat = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)), 0);
```

See as well: [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1319903/367456).

Comment: SPL `RecursiveIteratorIterator` class is the best possible solution when you have a mixed array (keys with both N dimension and keys as strings/ints/whatever not array).

Comment: It is return only array value not key. how can i get key & value both?

Comment: @ChiragPatel: Recursive iteration over (then multiple) array(s) often has key collisions. The recursive iteration however does provide keys as well, just set the second parameter `$use_keys` of `iterator_to_array()` to `true`, see http://php.net/iterator_to_array

Answer (score 26):

[As of PHP 5.6](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) this can be done more simply with [argument unpacking](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list).

```
$flat = array_merge(...$array);
```

Comment: As of PHP 7.4 this will also will work if $array has a count of zero (for exactly this use).

Comment: this is the most clear and simple solution today

Answer (score 13):

This is really all there is to it:

```
foreach($array as $subArray){
    foreach($subArray as $val){
        $newArray[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: its not linear or logN

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($a as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
        echo "$v2\n";
    }
}
```

where $a is your array name. 
[for details](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: This does not answer the question completly, he wants to populate a new array with the values. (However I do think they found a solution since the 2 years that this has been posted)

Comment: i also think that they found the result but i just wanted to share my view. thanks for the comment, no hard feelings :)

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.3 the shortest solution seems to be array_walk_recursive() with the new closures syntax:

```
function flatten(array $array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP5.6 there other way to solve this problem, combining the functions, `array_shift()` to remove the first elemente of the original array, `array_pus()` to add items an new array, the important thing is the of `...` splapt/elipse operator it will unpack the return of `array_shitf()` like an argument.

```
<?php

$arr = [
        ['foo', 'bar', 'hello'],
        ['world', 'love'],
        ['stack', 'overflow', 'yep', 'man', 'wow']
    ];

$new = [];
while($item = array_shift($arr)){
    array_push($new, ...$item);
}

print_r($new);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => foo
    [1] => bar
    [2] => hello
    [3] => world
    [4] => love
    [5] => stack
    [6] => overflow
    [7] => yep
    [8] => man
    [9] => wow
)
```

[Example - ideone](https://ideone.com/edtO6B)

Comment: Works only for single dimensional arrays. For mixed use, only working solution is `$new = iterator_to_array(new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveArrayIterator($myArray)), null);`

Answer (score 1):

I had used this code to resolve same type of problem. so you can also try this.

```
function array_flatten($array) { 

 if (!is_array($array))  
{ 
  return FALSE;  
}  
  $result = array(); 
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
  if (is_array($value))  
  {
   $result = array_merge($result, array_flatten($value));
  } 
  else  {
  $result[$key] = $value;   
  }  
}   
return $result; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will make

```
array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$blocked_dates = array(
                    '2014' => Array
                        (
                            '8' => Array
                                (
                                    '3' => '1',
                                    '4' => '1',                                     
                                    '6' => '1',                                     
                                    '10' => '1',
                                    '15' => '1',
                                    '25' => '1'

                                )

                        ),
                    '2015' => Array
                        (
                            '9' => Array
                                (
                                    '3' => '1',
                                    '4' => '1',                                    
                                    '6' => '1',                                     
                                    '10' => '1',
                                    '15' => '1',
                                    '25' => '1'

                                )

                        )    

                );
```

**RESUTL(ONE DIMENTIONAL ARRAY) :**

```
$unavailable_dates = array();
foreach ($blocked_dates as $year=>$months) {

    foreach ($months as $month => $days) {

        foreach ($days as $day => $value) {

            array_push($unavailable_dates,"$year-$month-$day");
        }

    }
}



$unavailable_dates = json_encode($unavailable_dates);
print_r($unavailable_dates);

OUTPUT : ["2014-8-3","2014-8-4","2014-8-6","2014-8-10","2014-8-15","2014-8-25","2015-9-3","2015-9-4","2015-9-6","2015-9-10","2015-9-15","2015-9-25"]
```

Answer (score -1):

The quickest solution would be to use this [array library](https://github.com/minwork/array):

```php
$flattened = Arr::flatten($yourArray);
```

which will produce exactly the array you want