# php multidimensional array get values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

This is my array in php **$hotels**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        [hotel_name] => Name
        [info] => info
        [rooms] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [room_name] => name
                        [beds] => 2
                        [boards] => Array
                            (
                                [board_id] => 1
                                [price] =>200.00
                            )
                    )
                )
        )
)
```

How can I get **board_id** and **price** I have tried few foreach loops but can't get the result

```
foreach($hotels as $row)
{
    foreach($row as $k)
    {
        foreach($k as $l)
        {
            echo $l['board_id'];
            echo $l['price'];
        }
    }
}
```

This code didn't work.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is the way to iterate on this array:

```
foreach($hotels as $row) {
       foreach($row['rooms'] as $k) {
             echo $k['boards']['board_id'];
             echo $k['boards']['price'];
       }
}
```

You want to iterate on the hotels and the rooms (the ones with numeric indexes), because those seem to be the "collections" in this case. The other arrays only hold and group properties.

Comment: This is the case of iterating. But it would be great if you can tell a short cut to get the $k['boards'] array only. Or I would say, I need to get the boards with board_id = 1.

Comment: @Jithin If you need the one with `board_id = 1`, it can be done, just browse the PHP manual, the [Array Functions section](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), you will find handy tools there if you need something nicer than `foreach`.

Answer (score 41):

For people who searched for `php multidimensional array get values` and actually want to solve problem comes from getting one column value from a 2 dimensinal array (like me!), here's a much elegant way than using `foreach`, which is [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

For example, if I only want to get `hotel_name` from the below array, and form to another array:

```
$hotels = [
    [
        'hotel_name' => 'Hotel A',
        'info' => 'Hotel A Info',
    ],
    [
        'hotel_name' => 'Hotel B',
        'info' => 'Hotel B Info',
    ]
];
```

I can do this using `array_column`:

```
$hotel_name = array_column($hotels, 'hotel_name');

print_r($hotel_name); // Which will give me ['Hotel A', 'Hotel B']
```

---

For the actual answer for this question, it can also be beautified by `array_column` and [`call_user_func_array('array_merge', $twoDimensionalArray);`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754980/how-to-convert-two-dimensional-array-to-one-dimensional-array-in-php5)

Let's make the data in PHP:

```
$hotels = [
    [
        'hotel_name' => 'Hotel A',
        'info' => 'Hotel A Info',
        'rooms' => [
            [
                'room_name' => 'Luxury Room',
                'bed' => 2,
                'boards' => [
                    'board_id' => 1,
                    'price' => 200
                ]
            ],
            [
                'room_name' => 'Non Luxy Room',
                'bed' => 4,
                'boards' => [
                    'board_id' => 2,
                    'price' => 150
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ],
    [
        'hotel_name' => 'Hotel B',
        'info' => 'Hotel B Info',
        'rooms' => [
            [
                'room_name' => 'Luxury Room',
                'bed' => 2,
                'boards' => [
                    'board_id' => 3,
                    'price' => 900
                ]
            ],
            [
                'room_name' => 'Non Luxy Room',
                'bed' => 4,
                'boards' => [
                    'board_id' => 4,
                    'price' => 300
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

And here's the calculation:

```
$rooms = array_column($hotels, 'rooms');
$rooms = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $rooms);
$boards = array_column($rooms, 'boards');

foreach($boards as $board){
    $board_id = $board['board_id'];
    $price = $board['price'];
    echo "Board ID is: ".$board_id." and price is: ".$price . "<br/>";
}
```

Which will give you the following result:

```
Board ID is: 1 and price is: 200
Board ID is: 2 and price is: 150
Board ID is: 3 and price is: 900
Board ID is: 4 and price is: 300
```

Comment: It's a short and good way to get the inner values on a single-dimension array.