# Php multidimentional array convert to one dimentional

Tags: php

I have an array which consist monthly information as shown below :

```
[appr] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => August
                        [approd] => 23
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => September
                        [approd] => 546
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [month] => October
                        [approd] => 234
                    )

            )
```

I want the output as below

```
[appr] => Array(
        August => 23,
        September => 546,
        October => 234
   )
```

can anybody help me to achieve this using php.

Comment: Use a foreach loop and then construct your final array.

Comment: Loop it through the array and create your customized array. Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I know loops can achieve what i required , but is there any built in functions in php to get it , any shortcut coz i dont want to use loops

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755001/4248328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a simple one-liner solution, use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)  functions.

Try this:

```
$array['appr'] = array_combine(array_column($array['appr'], "month"), array_column($array['appr'], "approd"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply loop in your `array` and create a new array

```
$array = array(array('month'=>'August','approd'=>'23'),array('month'=>'September','approd'=>'56'),array('month'=>'October','approd'=>'234'),);
$new = array();
foreach($array as $val) {
   $new['appr'][$val['month']] = $val['approd'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"One-line" solution using `array_column` function:

```
$arr['appr'] = array_column($arr['appr'], 'approd', 'month');

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [appr] => Array
        (
            [August] => 23
            [September] => 546
            [October] => 234
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `array_walk_recursive`:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'something',
    ),
    1 => array(
        'else',
    )
);


// If the keys are unique
$newArray = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v, $k) use (&$newArray) {
    $newArray[$k] = $v;
});

// If you have duplicate keys
$newArray = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($v) use (&$newArray) {
    $newArray[] = $v;
});
```

And finally output the result:

```
print_r($newArray);
```

#### Resources

- [array_walk_recursive - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)