# Create array not get perfect output

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have create array like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [14] => Array ( [selected] => selected ) ) [1] => Array ( [15] => Array ( [selected] => selected ) ) )
```

how to get the output like

```
Array ( [14] => Array ( [selected] => selected ) [15] => Array ( [selected] => selected ) )
```

PHP

```
$select_pic=$connection->createCommand("select * from sdmatts_collection_relation where furniture_id ='$fid'");
$multi_collection= $select_pic->queryAll();
$selectvalue= array();
foreach ($multi_collection as $fcol){
    $fmulti_collection[]   = array(
    $fcol['collection_id'] => array('selected' => 'selected'),);
}


I have create listbox dynamic select value in update time on yii1.
I use this code in yii1 listbox update time.

I use the static code 

 $selected   = array(
      '102' => array('selected' => 'selected'),
      '103' => array('selected' => 'selected'),
    );


also work listbox value are selected but i create dynamically that time not work.

my dynamic array is.

Array ( [0] => Array ( [14] => Array ( [selected] => selected ) ) [1] => Array ( [15] => Array ( [selected] => selected ) ) )

but still not working my listbox in select value.
```

so have can i create dynamic listbox in yii1 and add/edit time select the value.

thanks

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: it seems like both of the arrays are the same (wrong edit?)

Comment: both the array are same what is the error??

Comment: sorry my mistake just corrected it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit your question.

Comment: Can you show ur $multi_collection array data.......

Comment: @Shibon I believe that the first array's output in the question is the output of that variable.

Comment: please check this url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754980/how-to-convert-two-dimensional-array-to-one-dimensional-array-in-php5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<?php
$select_pic = $connection->createCommand("select * from sdmatts_collection_relation where furniture_id ='$fid'");
$multi_collection = $select_pic->queryAll();
$selectvalue = array();
foreach ($multi_collection as $fcol){
    $fmulti_collection[$fcol['collection_id']]   = array('selected' => 'selected');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `iterator_to_array`. This is faster than others.

```
$result = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($yourArry)), 0);
print_r($result); //Display your expected result.
```

**PHP CODE:**

```
$yourArry = Array ( Array ( "14" => Array ( "selected" => "selected" ) ), Array ( "15" => Array ( "selected" => "selected" ) ) );
$result = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($yourArry)), 0);
print_r($result);
```

**Result:**

```
   Array ( [0] => selected [1] => selected )
```

Comment: Instead of manipulating an existing array, why not just manipulating the creation of the array?

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating that array, use the `collection_id` variable as a key instead of `[]`:

Current code:

```
$fmulti_collection[]   = array(
    $fcol['collection_id'] => array('selected' => 'selected'),);
```

Change to:

```
$fmulti_collection[$fcol['collection_id']] =
     => array('selected' => 'selected'),);
```

**Notice:** Keep in mind that `$fcol['collection_id']` should be "unique", so if you have more than one element with the same collection_id value - it would be overwritten and then you'll have to use the first method and deal with that array's structure.