# converting different indexes values in arrays to another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => B
        )

    [1] => C
    [2] => Array
      (
           [0] => D
           [0] => E
      )
)
```

and I want to convert it like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        [0] => A
        [1] => B
        [2] => C
        [3] => D
        [4] => E
)
```

i.e I want all the values in the first array (irrespective of their indexes) to be aligned in the second array.

Comment: try `array_merge_recursive` with splat operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a custom script which merge arrays by your logic.

Example:

```
<?php
$a = [
    ['A', 'B'],
    'C',
    ['D', 'E']
];

$result = [];
foreach ($a as $v) {
    if (is_array($v))
        $result = array_merge($result, $v);
    else
        $result[] = $v;
}

print_r([$result]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user this :

```
$array = iterator_to_array(new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array)),0);
```

[I have copied from here how Turning multidimensional array into one-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754980/how-to-convert-two-dimensional-array-to-one-dimensional-array-in-php5)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array("A", "B"),
    1 => "C",
    2 => array("D", "E"),
    );
$result = array();
$response = arrayIndex($arr, $result);

function arrayIndex($arr, $result){
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value)){
                $result = $this->arrayIndex($value, $result);
            } else {
                array_push($result, $value);
            }
        }

        return $result;
}
```

NOTE: This function will convert n level of array elements into a single level array.