# Add to/merge json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, array-merge, array-push

Im building a tool that measures websites for various things.

Im building up an array of info through each check. Ill outline the logic below without loads of code.

```
var report = [];


 //do a check for an ssl cert, if true...      
    report.push({
      "ssl": "true"
    });

//do a check for analytics tag, if true...
    report.push({
      "analytics": "true"
    });

//Then I run the google insights api and add results to the array...
    report.push(JSON.parse(data));
```

My result is this...

```
{
    "ssl": "true"
},
{
    "analytics": "true"
},
{
    "captchaResult": "CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED",
    "kind": "pagespeedonline#result",
    "responseCode": 200,
```

Now I try to read through it

```
$report = file_get_contents("json.json");
$json = json_decode($report, true);
```

gives me..

```
[0] => Array (
    [ssl] => true
    )
[1] => Array (
    [analytics] => true
    )
[3=> Array ( [captchaResult] => CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED
[kind] => pagespeedonline#result
[responseCode] => 200)
```

Unfortunately I cant determine in which order array 1 and 2 will be generated.. so if I try and echo a result like so

```
echo $json[1]['ssl']
```

I would get Notice: Undefined index: ssl.

Ideally I would like to get the array like so:

```
[0] => Array (
    [ssl] => true
    [analytics] => true
    [captchaResult] => CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED
    [kind] => pagespeedonline#result
    [responseCode] => 200
)
```

So I can simply echo out like so, regardless of the order:

```
  echo $json['ssl'];
  echo $json['analytics'];
  echo $json['captureResult']; etc etc
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert two dimensional array to one dimensional array in php5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754980/how-to-convert-two-dimensional-array-to-one-dimensional-array-in-php5)

Comment: Or check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might also use [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).

Because the result is a single array, you should make sure not to use duplicate values for the key.

```
$result = [];
array_walk_recursive($arrays, function ($value, $key) use (&$result) {
    $result[$key] = $value;
});

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZbQ0rK)

That would give you:

```
Array
(
    [ssl] => 1
    [analytics] => 1
    [captchaResult] => CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED
    [kind] => pagespeedonline#result
    [responseCode] => 200
)
```

You could get your value using for example `echo $result['ssl'];`

Answer (score 0):

You could build the result yourself.

```
// base array default values
// we use $defaults because we assume the remainder of this task 
// will be performed for multiple websites inside of a loop
$defaults = array('ssl'=>false, 'analytics'=>false, 'captchaResult'=>'CAPTCHA_NOT_NEEDED', 'kind'=>'', 'responseCode'=>0) ;

// get a base copy of your array
$results = $defaults ;

// loop through your results
foreach($json as $values) {
    // get your key 
    $key = key($values) ;

    // get your value
    $results[$key] = $values[$key] ;
}
```

That will get you a predictable array of values. Change your defaults to the correct values