# How to convert multiple array to single array

Tags: php

Sorry for asking this silly question here. I am very new to PHP language.
I am trying to know how can i convert the array.
I want to convert this array to single array like.

Convert this :-

```
Array ( [0] => user ) 
Array ( [0] => user1 ) 
Array ( [0] => user2 ) 
Array ( [0] => user3 ) 
Array ( [0] => user8 ) 
Array ( [0] => user7 ) 
Array ( [0] => user6 )
```

Convert To :-

```
Array("user", "user1", "user2", "user3", "user4", "user5", "user6");
```

Comment: See [`array_merge()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Actually i am fetching it from database using mysqli_fetch_array() function.
Array i receive is in the format 
Array ( [0] => user ) Array ( [0] => user1 ) Array ( [0] => user2 ) Array ( [0] => user3 ) Array ( [0] => user8 ) Array ( [0] => user7 ) Array ( [0] => user6 )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert two dimensional array to one dimensional array in php5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754980/how-to-convert-two-dimensional-array-to-one-dimensional-array-in-php5)

Answer (score 1):

To "Merge" multiple arrays into one, you can use `array_merge()`

A good example would be:

```
$array_1 = array('user'); 
$array_2 = array('user1'); 
$array_3 = array('user2'); 
$combined_array = array_merge($array1,$array_2,$array_3); 
var_dump($combined_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for the replying.

Comment: it is my pleasure man!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $users[] = $row[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, aside from [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), for the case of an arbitrary number of subarrays, you could use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and build your final array:

```
$inArray = [['user'],['user1'],['user2'],['user3'],['user8'],['user7'],['user6']];

$inArray = array_reduce($inArray, function($arr, $elem){
    $arr[] = $elem[0];
    return $arr;
});
```

Of course, the straightforward solution would be to use [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$inArray = array_merge(...$inArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pack or collect all arrays into a parent array.
Then you only need to pass an array as a parameter when calling array_merge.
Update: it is better to use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$arr  = [];
$arr[] = array('user');
$arr[] = array('user1'); 
$arr[] = array('user2');

$one_dim_array = array_merge(...$arr);

//or better
$one_dim_array =  array_column($arr,0);

echo "<pre>".var_export($one_dim_array, true);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'user',
  1 => 'user1',
  2 => 'user2',
)
```

Try it yourself : [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ef3790802b79fde46a533b1f32a94f8643c0e604)