# PHP merge array of arrays into one array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I'm new to PHP and want to make an array of more than one array into a single object/array and where the number of child arrays is not necessarily known.

So this:

```
$events = [
  [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
  ],
  [
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
  ]
];
```

Becomes:

```
$mergedEvents = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "six",
];
```

Tried:
`$mergedEvents = array_merge($events[0], $events[1]);` works if you have static number but I need to flatten(?) it when child array count is unknown.

Comment: `array_merge(...$events)`

Comment: pls check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8755001/9042437