# how to convert the associative array to single dimensional array in php

Tags: php

i m getting the array as below

```
$teachers=array(array('post_id' => "81",'video_id' => array("81","73")), array('post_id' => "81",'video_id' => array("81","73")));
```

if all the key-value are same i would like to display only one key-value ( as in above example) as below :

i would like to display

```
{ post_id -> array([0]-> 81 [1]-> 73) }
```

And if its different as in the below example it should display both the arrays..

```
{ $teachers=array(array('post_id' => "81",'video_id' => array("81","73")), 
array('post_id' => "81",'video_id' => array("81", "59")));}
```

i would like to display

```
{post_id -> array([0]-> 81 [1]-> 73 [2] -> 59) }
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php#92195

Comment: Is this the same question that you asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15445624/how-to-convert-multidimensional-associative-array-into-single-dimensional-array - except you changed the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function array_values_recursive($ary)  {
    $lst = array();
    foreach( array_keys($ary) as $k ) {
        $v = $ary[$k];
        if (is_scalar($v)) {
            $lst[] = $v;
        } elseif (is_array($v)) {
            $lst = array_merge($lst,array_values_recursive($v));
        }
    }
    return array_values(array_unique($lst)); // used array_value function for rekey
}
    $teachers=array(
        array('post_id' => "81",'video_id' => array("81","73")),
        array('post_id' => "81",'video_id' => array("81", "59")));

$flat = array_values_recursive($teachers);
print_r($flat); //OUTPUT : Array ( [0] => 81 [1] => 73 [2] => 59 )
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can still use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
$teachers = array_unique($teachers);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 81
            [video_id] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 81
                    [1] => 73
                )
        )
)
```

http://codepad.org/eC4FR2fq

However note, that it may not work if you have different set of keys except `post_id` and `video_id` because

> Note: Two elements are considered equal if and only if (string) $elem1
>   === (string) $elem2. In words: when the string representation is the same. The first element will be used.