# How to merge array of arrays into one php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array.

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => IT Software - Application Programming, Maintenance 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => IT Software - eCommerce, Internet Technologies 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [title] => IT Software - Client/ Server Programming
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [title] => IT Software - Other 
            )

    )
```

Would like to get the resultant array as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => IT Software - Application Programming, Maintenance

    [1] => IT Software - eCommerce, Internet Technologies 

    [2] => IT Software - Client/ Server Programming

    [3] => IT Software - Other 


)
```

can i get a simple one liner other than `array_column()` because im running php version below 5.5. I tried `$funcmerged = array_reduce($functionalres, 'array_merge', array());` but iam not getting desired result.

Comment: if you have PHP 5.5 or greater you can also use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Rather than "fixing" this one, perhaps it would be better to create the array in the first place to not contain a subarray for each element in the first place? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning multidimensional array into one-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611313/turning-multidimensional-array-into-one-dimensional-array)

Comment: can i get a simple one liner other than array_column() because im running php version below 5.5. I tried $funcmerged = array_reduce($functionalres, 'array_merge', array()); but iam not getting desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a pretty good solution

[How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

```
function flatten(array $array) {
        $return = array();
        array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
        return $return;
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$new = array();
foreach($yourArray as $value) {
    $new[] = $value['title'];
}
var_dump($new);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be

```
$newArr = array();
foreach($currentArr as $key=>$val){
    $newArr[] = $val['title'];
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
<?php
$newarray=array();
$array=array
(
    "0" => array("title"=>"IT Software - Application Programming, Maintenance"),
    "1"     => array("title"=>"IT Software - eCommerce, Internet Technologies   "),
    "2"    => array("title"=>"IT Software - Client/ Server Programming"),
    "3"    => array("title"=>"IT Software - Other")
); 

         foreach($array as $key =>$arrayvalue)
         {
         $newarray[]=$arrayvalue['title'];
         }
print_r($newarray);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
    Array ( [0] => IT Software - Application Programming, Maintenance 
[1] => IT Software - eCommerce, Internet Technologies   
[2] => IT Software - Client/ Server Programming 
[3] => IT Software - Other )
```