# PHP change array format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hope all of you doing well.

Actually I want to change the array format.

I have an array like in below.

```
Array
(
    [or] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Table.first_name LIKE ] => abc%
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Table.last_name LIKE ] => abc%
                )
        )
)
```

I want to change it in below type.

```
[or] => Array
        (
            [Table.first_name LIKE ] => abc%,
            [Table.last_name LIKE ] => abc%
        )
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning multidimensional array into one-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611313/turning-multidimensional-array-into-one-dimensional-array)

Comment: How do you generate this array? Show the relevant code. Or do you wish to alter the array after it's generated?

Comment: The code is too long, I am developing the advance search section for my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code:-

```
$result = [];
    foreach($array['or'] as $record){
      foreach($record as $k=>$v){
        $result['or'][$k] = $v;
      }
    }
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

**output**:-

```
Array
(
    [or] => Array
        (
            [Table.first_name LIKE ] => abc%
            [Table.last_name LIKE ] => abc%
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
foreach ($yourArray[0] as $entry)
{

    $newArray[$yourArray[0]] = $entry[0];
}
```