# How to combine multiple arrays into a single array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

Good morning have the following arrays would like to know how to combine them into a single array?

```
Array(
[name_option] => Tamanho
[name_option_value] => Grande) Array(
[name_option] => Cor
[name_option_value] => Amarelo) Array(
[name_option] => Tamanho
[name_option_value] => Medio) Array (
[name_option] => Cor
[name_option_value] => Azul) Array (
[name_option] => Tamanho
[name_option_value] => Pequeno ) Array(
[name_option] => Cor
[name_option_value] => Verde )
```

Comment: have you tried array_merge function? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning multidimensional array into one-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8611313/turning-multidimensional-array-into-one-dimensional-array)

Answer (score 0):

```
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
$new_array = array_merge($a1,$a2);
print_r($new_array);
```

More Details at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_merge.asp

Answer (score 0):

you could combine them into a multidimensional array:

```
<?php
$a = [];
$a[] = [
    'name_option' => 'Tamanho',
    'name_option_value' => 'Grande'
];
$a[] = [
    'name_option' => 'Cor',
    'name_option_value' => 'Amarelo'
];
$a[] = [
    'name_option' => 'Tamanho',
    'name_option_value' => 'Medio'
];
$a[] = [
    'name_option' => 'Cor',
    'name_option_value' => 'Azul'
];
$a[] = [
    'name_option' => 'Tamanho',
    'name_option_value' => 'Pequeno'
];
$a[] = [
    'name_option' => 'Cor',
    'name_option_value' => 'Verde'
];

print_r($a);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name_option] => Tamanho
            [name_option_value] => Grande
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name_option] => Cor
            [name_option_value] => Amarelo
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name_option] => Tamanho
            [name_option_value] => Medio
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name_option] => Cor
            [name_option_value] => Azul
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name_option] => Tamanho
            [name_option_value] => Pequeno
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name_option] => Cor
            [name_option_value] => Verde
        )

)
```

or rename the keys (e.g. add an index) to prevent override